# dropbox api authentication SSL error

Tags: dropbox

I try to be authenticated using [Dropbox-php-sdk](https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk). Therefore i use localhost development environment without ssl. Is that possible or not as i get the following error:

```
$callbackUrl = "http://localhost/dropboxphp/finish.php";

$accessToken = $authHelper->getAccessToken($code, $state, $callbackUrl);
echo $accessToken->getToken();
```

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to my problem even for localhost development using Wamp or other similar packages for Dropbox PHP SDK reading this [useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate).

Regards